# Main activity starts activity with both modules of my android project

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello guys so my project has 2 modules

> app module  (package com.licenta.andresadrian.shoppingcart)
>
> barcodescanner module (package com.github.softotalss.barcodescanner)

Here is how my main activity is defined in AndroidManifest of my app module:

```
       package="com.licenta.andresadrian.shoppingcart">  //Package set at the beginning


         <activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Here is how it's defined in my MainActivity.java from app module:

```
import com.licenta.andresadrian.shoppingcart.R; //importing the resource files

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Somehow I get this error when trying to run the app:

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.github.softotalss.barcodescanner/com.licenta.andresadrian.shoppingcart.view.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>
> Error type 3 Error: Activity class
>   {com.github.softotalss.barcodescanner/com.licenta.andresadrian.shoppingcart.view.MainActivity}
>   does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //U need to edit both  

       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

  ///////// 

   }
```

Comment: Actually <activity android:name=".view.MainActivity"> comes from the fact that my  MainActivity is in a folder named "view"

Answer (score 0):

Checklist

Firstly package name in build.gradle

Project correctly import barcode scanner module in build.gradle

If you are using kotlin check configuration